# Transparently replace pop-up window with YUI Panel

Tags: javascript, iframe, yui, domdocument, popupwindow

Long time reader, first time poster... This is my first question here, so I'd appreciate kindness! :)

**Background** - We develop a CGI web application (C & HTML/JavaScript) that started in 1991. As such, the code base has some primitive ways about it... e.g. popups, framesets, etc. Anyway, I'm developing a newer and mobile-friendly version, using more client-focused code (JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3, YUI3). This is simply a new parent window that uses an embedded iframe to contain any older code, whenever it has to run for some reason. Occasionally, the iframe portion of the app (the older code) will need to fire a pop-up window... which is where my problem comes up, next...

**My problem** - The whole thing must run nicely in a single iOS UIWebView instance - so, no popups allowed! I also cannot modify the existing code-base to get rid of the popups or change their behavior. The old code-base must be able to transparently use its existing `win = window.open(...)`, and `win.document.write(...)` calls.

So, I devised an override of the `window.open(...)` method *(whenever called within the old app's iframe)* with a custom method to instead show a YUI-Panel dialog in the newer parent document. I've gotten the YUI-Panel showing whenever the old code calls a popup, but I'm having trouble transferring the pop-up's document (from CGI) to the YUI-Panel.

I'm now wondering if I've over-engineered it. Has anyone else done something like this?

My code is pretty complex, so I hesitate to "spam" my first question with it all... more than happy to share it, if anyone's interested, though.

---

My solution...
In the meantime, I'm just doing a `document.write()` call with string data derived from `XMLSerializer.serializeToString(MyDocumentObject)`